# How to position images on path

Tags: javascript, html, svg

For text, I could use textpath, but how do I position images on a path or in specific irregular shapes(e.g triangle/circle)?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `getPointAtLength(length)` which returns an object representing the position.

Here is the API doc: [SVG getPointAtLength documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength)

With this you will be able to create any path shape you want. Then do a for loop in which you calculate the point along your path for an increasing length on each iteration.

```
  var pos;
  for (var i = 0, len = 0; i < 10; i++, len+=10){
    pos = yourPath.getPointAtLength(len);
    //Now set your items position to pos.x, pos.y
  }
```

Comment: This isn't a Raphaël specific method, it's [standard SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength). So, no special library needed (unless you want to use Raphaël for other reasons).